# Infinite loop when trying to synchronize GTK entries

Tags: c, gtk

I'm writing a "converter" program in GTK, where I have 2 `gtk_entry`s and (ideally) editing one would change the other.

However, I find myself in an infinite loop -- changing one changes the other, which changes the other, which changes the other ...

I'm guessing that is because I'm using the `changed` signal, when I really need some kind of "user-edited-this-field" signal as opposed to "computer-edited-this-field".

My code currently looks something like this:

```
year= gtk_entry_new ();
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (year), "changed",
                  G_CALLBACK (Update), (gpointer) "one");
```

(I tried using "one" and "two" to indicate "converting in this direction" vs "converting in that direction" but it didn't help.)

and my "Update" function ends with

```
gtk_entry_set_text( GTK_ENTRY (day), s);
```

Is there a signal I should be using that specifies "take this action when the user changes the text in this field, but not when the computer changes the text in this field" ?

I know that I could create a pair of "activate" buttons, one for each direction, but I'm trying to be snazzy and auto-update.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GTK, but it might be possible to check if the value actually *was* changed (i.e. compare against an old value)

Answer (score 1):

The signal you asked for does not exist but this should work:

```
g_signal_handlers_block_by_func (day, day_changed_cb, userdata_of_day_change_cb);
gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (day), s);
g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func (day, day_changed_cb, userdata_of_day_change_cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of the suggestions.  I'm going to move in a different direction more in line with my skills.  Thanks.

Since it annoys me to see questions closed with simply "Never mind, I figured it out" ...

I created a pair of radio buttons, and depending on which button is selected, I update one set of fields from the other set of fields.  To make it even more obvious, I decided to set up both a set of "entries" and a set of "labels."  When I update side A, then I hide the B-side entries and show the B-side labels.  When I update side B, then I hide the A-side entries and show the A-side labels, and hide the B-side labels and show the B-side entries.

I wish I knew how to "close" my own question.